# Does "I got the bag off the table" mean I took it off the table with some level of difficulty?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Some dictionaries say "**[to get](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)**" means "to move sometimes with difficulty.

For example, "**I got on the bus**", "**I got the sofa through the door**"

What I think is that because the platform of the bus is quite high and you need some effort to raise your leg high enough to step on it or else you might hurt yourself if you're not very careful. Personally, I hate "**stepping on the bus**" because it is quite hard work, not easy at all.

I think "**I took the bag off the table**" is neutral as it may or may not be difficult for me to take the bag off.

However, "**I got the bag off the table**" might mean it is a bit difficult for me to do it.

Is it correct that "**I got the bag off the table**" mean I took it off the table with some level of difficulty?

Answer (score 5):

It *could* mean that, but it could equally well mean *I went to fetch the bag.*

The verb **get** has many shades of meaning in different contexts. To *get on a bus* doesn't have any connotations of requiring a particular effort - you can just as well *get in the car* or *get into bed.*